# How do I get rid of. 0 in Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
a = 28.85
b = 2000
print(a*b)
```

Result 57700.0

`select name from fake limit 57700.0 ,10`
This sentence is incorrect.

Comment: `print(int(a*b))` ?

Comment: Do you want to get rid of the `.0` in the screen output or in the actual data?

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying a float with an int naturally gives you a float as an answer.

So, as @Rakesh suggested, truncate it with `int(a*b)`.

Beware that you will lose everything after the dot...

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the result as `float` if you use `format` in your `print` statement and cut all numbers behind the dot.

```
print("{:0.0f}".format(a * b))
```